# Combine data from two mysql tables in HTML table Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Trying to make one html table where is showing what login users choose.
One login auth users and one form data.
Here data is showing on page but scramled in table.
Homedata is showing twice.
Here is my index page where im trying to do:

```
 <table class="table" id="users-info">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">#</th>
                          <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                          <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                          <th scope="col">Naional Number</th>
                          <th scope="col">Device</th>
                          <th scope="col">Reimbursment</th>
                          <th scope="col">Warranty</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                     @if(count($users) > 0)
                                @foreach($users as $user)

                                    <tr>
                                      <th scope="row">{{ $user->id }}</th>
                                      <td>{{ $user->firstname }}</td>
                                      <td>{{ $user->lastname }}</td>
                                      <td>{{ $user->phone }}

                                    @foreach($homedata as $homedatas)

                                          <td>{{$homedatas->device}}</td>
                                          <td>{{$homedatas->reimburse_Pension}}</td>
                                          <td>{{$homedatas->bonus_remainder}}</td>          
                                    @endforeach
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach     
                            @endif  
                      </tbody>
                </table>
```

Please help.
if there is another way please feel free suggest.

Comment: You will probably have to provide us with some test data, such as what is the value of `$users`.  Even if it's made up data, as long as it produces the same issues.

Comment: I fetched all from database $users = User::all();  id, firstname, lastname etc ... but i think problem is how to present all data in one table with FOREACH or on some other way

Comment: I don't use laravel or blade, (but I know what they are) and I can tell you this part is probably not what you want `@foreach($homedata as $homedatas)` because this will created many `td` elements and you defined the table with `7` columns in `thead` so if you make `18` from that loop everything will be messed up, that is just HTML.  You may want to combine that data with users if it's for many users, or you may want to make a sub-table for it, if its many records per user.

Answer (score 0):

Hey everyone who share the same problem.
I add in second foreach ->slice(0, 1) and that foreach just going once, that automaticaly means no duplicate data :)